# CocoaPods conflict on install second pod

Tags: git, module, cocoapods, alamofire

When trying to install another module in my project, the first one is uninstalled. Why does it happen? What am I doing wrong?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

  target 'FadbApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  #pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.3' //This is previous Pod
  pod 'SRKControls', :git =>'https://github.com/reeichert/SRKControls.git'

end
```

And my return

[Terminal status - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgJPd.png)

Why the other module is uninstalled? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `#` thing before `pod 'Alamofire'`? That denotes a comment!

> Aren't comments denoted by `//`?

They are in Swift, but the file you're working with here is the `Podfile`. It is basically a Ruby script. In Ruby, comments are denoted by `#`. In other words, you accidentally commented out the line to install Alamofire.

Remove `#` and you'll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

The line for the `Alamofire` pod is commented out, so cocoapods is correctly removing it as you asked it.

If you want to have both pods, you need to remove the `#` at the beginning of the `pod Alamofire ...` line.